# Rails: Include nested objects in json response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I´m trying to write a json response that will include my objects associations. This is my object structure:

```
Category
  - sub_categories
  - options
     - city
```

I going to respond with a list of categories that will include sub_categories and options AND the city object for each option. This is what I have now:

```
categories.as_json(:include => [:sub_categories, :options => :city])
```

which gives me "TypeError (can't clone Symbol):" server error.

If I try:

```
categories.as_json(:include => [:sub_categories, :options])
```

it works but I need to include the city-object for each options as well.

How can I do this?

Comment: have you tried using [representers](https://github.com/apotonick/representable) , it will not only help you to solve the problem mentioned but also do lot more than that

Comment: There are nice gems to create complex json, like Rabl. But in your case, I think the issue is that you have to use the `:include` key for options too. Take a look at the last example under as_json here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON.html#method-i-as_json